# InsertRows in QAbstractItemModel with a QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to make a [QTreeView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html) work with a [QSortFilterProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html). I wrote a minimal working example (which is unfortunately not so minimal due to the complexity of the issue). The complete code is:

```py
import logging
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys


class DBObject:
    def __init__(self, name, parent, children=None):
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = children or list()

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"name: {self.name}, parent: {self.parent.name if self.parent is not None else '-'}"


class Model(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, root, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._root = root

    def columnCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return 1

    def rowCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if not parent.isValid():
            return 1

        parentItem = parent.internalPointer()
        rowCount = len(parentItem.children)
        logging.info(f"rowCount({parentItem}): rowCount={rowCount}")
        return rowCount

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        item = index.internalPointer()
        parentItem = item.parent

        logging.info(f"parent({item}): parent={parentItem}")
        if parentItem is None:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        else:
            if parentItem.parent is None:
                return self.createIndex(0, 0, parentItem)
            else:
                return self.createIndex(parentItem.parent.children.index(parentItem), 0, parentItem)

    def index(self, row, column, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if not parent.isValid():
            if row != 0 or column != 0:
                return QtCore.QModelIndex()
            else:
                logging.info(f"index({row}, {column}, None): index={self._root}")
                return self.createIndex(0, 0, self._root)

        parentItem = parent.internalPointer()

        if 0 <= row < len(parentItem.children):
            logging.info(f"index({row}, {column}, {parentItem}): index={parentItem.children[row]}")
            return self.createIndex(row, column, parentItem.children[row])
        else:
            logging.info(f"index({row}, {column}, {parentItem}): index=None")
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def data(self, index, role=None):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        item = index.internalPointer()

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return item.name
        else:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.Qt.NoItemFlags

        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def setData(self, index, value, role=None):
        if not index.isValid():
            return False

        item = index.internalPointer()

        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            item.name = value

            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [role])

            return True
        else:
            return False

    def insertRows(self, row, count, parent):
        self.beginInsertRows(parent, row, row + count - 1)

        parentItem = parent.internalPointer()

        for i in range(count):
            parentItem.children.append(DBObject("new", parentItem))

        self.endInsertRows()

        self.layoutChanged.emit()

        return True


class ProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, root, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._root = root


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__()

        self._root = root

        self.setMinimumSize(640, 480)

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(centralWidget)

        self._treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self)
        layout.addWidget(self._treeView)

        self._model = Model(self._root, self)
        self._proxyModel = ProxyModel(self._root, self)
        self._proxyModel.setSourceModel(self._model)
        self._treeView.setModel(self._proxyModel)

        self._treeView.expandAll()

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add")
        layout.addWidget(button)

        button.clicked.connect(self._Clicked)

    def _Clicked(self):
        self._model.insertRow(len(self._root.children), self._model.index(0, 0, QtCore.QModelIndex()))

        self._model.layoutChanged.emit()
        self._treeView.expandAll()


def main():
    root = DBObject("root", None)

    items = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
    for x in items:
        child = DBObject(x + "0", root)
        root.children.append(child)

        for y in items:
            child.children.append(DBObject(y + "1", child))

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWindow = MainWindow(root)
    mainWindow.show()

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Up until now I was only interested in displaying available data and I was able to select and even edit the data displayed. However, now I would also like to add data to the model and I fail to do so.

In order to add data I need to overload the [insertRows](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#insertRows) method below and I have a couple of questions regarding that:

```
def insertRows(self, row, count, parent):
    self.beginInsertRows(parent, row, row + count - 1)

    parentItem = parent.internalPointer()

    for i in range(count):
        parentItem.children.append(DBObject("new", parentItem))

    self.endInsertRows()
    self.layoutChanged.emit()

    return True
```

1. Does this method need to be in the derived class of QAbstractItemModel or QSortFilterProxyModel?
2. Do I need to use [createIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#createIndex) inside this method?
3. Do I need to call [layoutAboutToBeChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#layoutAboutToBeChanged) inside this method?

The problem arises when I start selecting different items in the tree view and also adding new data. The crashes range from segmentation fauls to `QSortFilterProxyModel: index from wrong model passed to mapFromSource`.

I fed my model trough the model test suite found [here](https://github.com/bgr/PyQt5_modeltest/blob/master/modeltest.py) and everything checks out fine. The QSortFilterProxyModel I use does not do any filtering or sorting in this example, so the issue is unrelated to that.

Any help, hint or feedback is appreciated.

Comment: We are having similar issues even with a read-only model. One difference I see is that your model is having root-node whereas all examples I see consider the root-node as invisible. Is there a special reason for your project to show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to emit the layoutChanged signal. Another bug is that the `index()` method sets the parent's default parameter to None instead of QModelIndex. Also I see unnecessary to use *args and **kwargs in methods that don't use it and that already have predefined behavior and arguments.

```py
import logging
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class DBObject:
    def __init__(self, name, parent, children=None):
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = children or list()

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"name: {self.name}, parent: {self.parent.name if self.parent is not None else '-'}"


class Model(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, root, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._root = root

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if not parent.isValid():
            return 1

        parentItem = parent.internalPointer()
        rowCount = len(parentItem.children)
        logging.info(f"rowCount({parentItem}): rowCount={rowCount}")
        return rowCount

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        item = index.internalPointer()
        parentItem = item.parent

        logging.info(f"parent({item}): parent={parentItem}")
        if parentItem is None:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        else:
            if parentItem.parent is None:
                return self.createIndex(0, 0, parentItem)
            else:
                return self.createIndex(
                    parentItem.parent.children.index(parentItem), 0, parentItem
                )

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if not parent.isValid():
            if row != 0 or column != 0:
                return QtCore.QModelIndex()
            else:
                logging.info(f"index({row}, {column}, None): index={self._root}")
                return self.createIndex(0, 0, self._root)

        parentItem = parent.internalPointer()

        if 0 <= row < len(parentItem.children):
            logging.info(
                f"index({row}, {column}, {parentItem}): index={parentItem.children[row]}"
            )
            return self.createIndex(row, column, parentItem.children[row])
        else:
            logging.info(f"index({row}, {column}, {parentItem}): index=None")
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        item = index.internalPointer()

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return item.name
        else:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.Qt.NoItemFlags

        return (
            QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
            | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable
            | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable
        )

    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return False

        item = index.internalPointer()

        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            item.name = value

            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [role])

            return True
        else:
            return False

    def insertRows(self, row, count, parent):
        self.beginInsertRows(parent, row, row + count - 1)

        parentItem = parent.internalPointer()

        for i in range(count):
            parentItem.children.append(DBObject("new", parentItem))
        self.endInsertRows()
        return True


class ProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, root, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._root = root


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__()

        self._root = root

        self.setMinimumSize(640, 480)

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(centralWidget)

        self._treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self)
        layout.addWidget(self._treeView)

        self._model = Model(self._root, self)
        self._proxyModel = ProxyModel(self._root, self)
        self._proxyModel.setSourceModel(self._model)
        self._treeView.setModel(self._proxyModel)

        self._treeView.expandAll()

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add")
        layout.addWidget(button)

        button.clicked.connect(self._Clicked)

    def _Clicked(self):
        self._model.insertRow(
            len(self._root.children), self._model.index(0, 0, QtCore.QModelIndex())
        )
        self._treeView.expandAll()


def main():
    root = DBObject("root", None)

    items = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
    for x in items:
        child = DBObject(x + "0", root)
        root.children.append(child)

        for y in items:
            child.children.append(DBObject(y + "1", child))

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWindow = MainWindow(root)
    mainWindow.show()

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The method parameter are due to my IDE which copies the parameter from PyQt5.
The key information is leaving out the layoutChanged as well as the layoutAboutToBeChanged signals. Without these signals all errors are removed.
Thank you for your help.